# How can I support multiple domains in one htaccess file?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm in a hosting environment where I can't modify the Apache conf files directly, so I am relying on htaccess files.

I have a public_html directory and I want to set it up so that I can have subdirectories like the following, so that when visitors access alpha.com in their browsers, they get the content from that directory, and so on:

```
public_html/alpha.com   # Used when visitors access alpha.com
public_html/bravo.com   # Used when visitors access bravo.com
public_html/charlie.com # Used when visitors access charlie.com
```

How can I do this with an htaccess file in the root of public_html?

I don't want to use any kind of client-side redirect. I want to map these on the server side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?alpha\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^((?!alpha\.com/).*)$ /alpha.com/$1 [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?bravo\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^((?!bravo\.com/).*)$ /bravo.com/$1 [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?charlie\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^((?!charlie\.com/).*)$ /charlie.com/$1 [NC,L]
```

Or if you always use the same name for the directory, you can use:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?((?:alpha|bravo|charlie).com) [NC]
RewriteCond %1::%{REQUEST_URI} !^(.*?)::/\1/?
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /%1/$1 [NC,L]
```